# Writing flutter test involving selecting a dropdown menu item

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm writing a flutter test that involves selecting a dropdown menu item from a `DropdownButtonFormField`. After I tap the dropdown and then try to tap on one of the menu items, it selects a particular item always, not the one I want. Suppose the dropdown has 3 items, like so: `['Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C']`

```
await tester.tap(find.byKey(ValueKey("dropdown_key")));
await tester.pump();
await tester.tap(find.text('Item A'));
await tester.pump();
```

It will select `Item B` always. What's missing?

Comment: You should include your whole test code.  I am running into a similar issue, but I am selecting the 1st item always.

Comment: same here. I do this: `await tester.tap(find.text('Item A').first);
await tester.pump();`

Comment: I've been having this same issue for months and in fact skipped a few tests. Have you had any luck?

Answer (score 3):

This is what im doing and works like a treat!

```
// First select the drop down box
await tester.tap(find.text('Vehicle type *'));
await tester.pumpAndSettle();
// Then select the value in it
await tester.tap(find.text('Car').first);
await tester.pumpAndSettle();
```

Comment: have you tried scrolling? scrollUntilVisible doesn't seem to work because the widgets seem to be showing from the start

Comment: Worked for me, thanks, I used find.byKey(keyName) to first get the dropdownformfield